# No Relationship Usage of Database Documentation

Tags: android, sql, erd

I have an android application that uses SQLLite to store data locally. The problem comes when I want to document this application.
 I didn't use foreign key in the tables, in other words, I use the tables independently.
The question is there a better way to document this other than ERD?

Comment: any reason you didn't use foreign keys? Are they unnecessary for some reason - all your data is unrelated, perhaps? Most databases end up needing them,  in general

Comment: I want to store collection of data and prefernces didn't provide easy access to that

Comment: So instead of an ERD what do you want? Just a list of all the fields or something? It's unclear what kind of documentation you're hoping to see. And are you asking if there's a way to create it automatically? Again, it's not fully clear what you want.

Comment: I just want the format of the documentation for such data. Do I just have to list all the column per table or there is already a document format for this case

Comment: you need to list whatever you think people need to know about your software. We can't really advise you about what is or isn't important in your scenario. We don't even know precisely what this data is, so it's hard to say how you could present it.